# Push notifications in android: unable to invoke Toast from GCMIntentService

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to setup Push Notifications with GCM on the Android platform.

When I do this within GCMIntentService:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Toast.makeText(context,intent.getStringExtra("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I get the following error: `sending message to a Handler on a dead pool`

But when I run the same line anywhere within my main Intent, it works just fine.

I tried adding the fix found on google of adding "Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");" to my onCreate method inside the main intent. But that doesn't help.

**Is it possible to offload the message from GCMIntentService onto my main activity and simply call Toast from there?**

Answer (score 3):

U should use a handler for this. The code is as follows:

```
private void handleMessage( Intent intent )
{
    final String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");

  Thread t = new Thread()
    {

        public void run()
        {

            Message myMessage = new Message();
            Bundle resBundle = new Bundle();
            resBundle.putString( "message", message );
            myMessage.setData( resBundle );
            handler.sendMessage( myMessage );
        }
    };
    t.start();
 }

private Handler handler = new Handler()
{

      public void handleMessage( Message msg )
            {

             Toast.makeText( getBaseContext(), msg.getData().getString( "message" ), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }
};
```

This code should be implemented on GCM service which is handling message.

Answer (score 0):

What about change the context to `Toast.makeText(context, ...)` to `getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: That didn't help. Using status notifications instead of Toast did the trick though.

Comment: Yes, but this is a totally different style of notification. You only want to ever use status notifications outside the app.